# Select all span elements except those which class contains the word icon

Tags: css

I'm implementing the following CSS Selector

**Select all `span` elements except those which class contains the word icon**

So the following seems to be working:

```
.music-site-refresh span:not([class*="icon-"]) {
  font-family:Montserrat, sans-serif;
}
```

But I thought it should be like this:

```
.music-site-refresh span:not(span[class*="icon-"]) {
  font-family:Montserrat, sans-serif;
}
```

But the second one doesn't work in my testbed.

Could anyone explain me which one is correct and why?

Here is some barfed html for example purposes:

```
<span class="cmImageSliderIndicatorActive icon-circle-blank" data-set="0"></span>

<div class="janrain-share-providerslist-provider-image janrain-provider-icon-grayscale-email"></div>
```

There are more icons. It is not an `icon` class, that is why I'm using `class*`

Comment: imho you should right it like this : `.music-site-refresh span:not(.icon)` related to the Mozilla Developer Network example for `:not` CSS selector [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot)

Comment: that would be amazing, but font awesome icons come like icon-something

Comment: btw I have no control on the content of the page

Comment: @Zeratops is right in you don't need to select the class by selecting it as an attribute. `:not(.class)` is ideal

Comment: @Anagio the icon classes are not `.icon` they are for example: `.icon-one`, `.icon-two`, `.icon-number-5`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CSS, `:not` is considered a *pseudo-class*, which puts it into the same category as other pseudo-classes like `:hover`, `:focus`, etc.

I think it makes more sense to explain this when thinking of one of those other pseudo-classes.. let's look at `:hover` as an example.. when you write a selector using `:hover`, it would look something like this:

```
div:hover {}
```

You can see that the colon joins the `hover` pseduo-class to the element.. which is where that "pseudo-class" name comes from.. It's not a real CSS class, but it acts the same way as one. It applies as a **modifier to the original element in the selector**.

So now let's look at `:not` again. When you are using this pseudo-class on a selector, it's joined to it.. so saying `:not(span.icon)` can kind of be thought of writing it out like this, to simplify it out a fair bit:

```
not spanspan.icon
```

which doesn't really make sense.

Comment: that makes sense... The icons are not `icon` they are `icon-mail` `icon-square` or `icon-gray-box`. I have no control on previous content. But your explanation is top notch. Accepted